# How to access (read/write) advanced file EXIF/metadata in the Dropbox JavaScript API?

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

How to access (read/write) advanced file metadata in the Dropbox JavaScript API?

I'm talking about things like e.g.: MacOS file tags. Or the camera model inside the EXIF data.

Please note that `dbx.filesGetMetadata(arg)` does not provide very detailed metadata... Almost only dropbox specific metadata actually.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/How-to-access-read-write-advanced-file-EXIF-metadata-in-the/m-p/214212#M10957 ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to Greg.

The Dropbox API unfortunately doesn't natively return Mac OS file metadata/xattrs, or the full EXIF information for a file. The Dropbox API currently only natively returns a few pieces of basic media information in `FilesFileMetadata.media_info`, e.g., if you set `FilesGetMetadataArg.include_media_info` to true when calling `filesGetMetadata` or `filesListFolder`/`filesListFolderContinue`.

To get any other metadata embedded in the file content, you'll need to download the file content and parse it out client-side.